# Problems reading Windows Key on 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, windows

I want to read with a simple c# application the windows key from the registry. But on a x64 machine I recieve only BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB as the key and that is wrong... How can I fix that problem?

```
RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion");
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's rather incomplete.  What *value* are you actually reading?

Comment: @ThomasSebastianJensen It is working correctly on my 64 bit Windows 7 laptop. I am not sure why you are having an issue, unless it has something to do with localization.

Comment: That is interesting. I'm getting only BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB on a German Windows 7 x64.

Comment: What do you have in your data Byte array? does it look right?

Comment: How can I post the code, because it is my key, but there are many 0 in the array. So he converts the 0 to a B and so I'm getting this special key.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to post the key, Double check the registry to see what the DigitProductID looks like.

Comment: How can I check if everything looks fine?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [Web Site](http://davehope.co.uk/Blog/network-cd-key-recovery/) that makes CD Key recovery software and this [Windows7Forums thread](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-software/52182-i-have-problen-find-product-key-windows-7-i-need-help-2.html), the existance of all B's for the product ID is indicative of a MAK(Multiple Activation Key) key.

From First link:

> The B’s means the cd key is not stored in your computer, so cannot be recovered. That can be due to a few reasons:
>
> A MAK was used for activation;
>   SLMGR was used to remove the key from the windows registry,
>   or You’re running a pirated version of Windows.

From Second Link

> This is a big problem when an administrator sets up many PCs with a
>   volume license key. Because everyone can extract the VLC key and use
>   it for additional installations. Because this reason the VLC key is
>   automatically deleted from the registry after activation. And after
>   this all key finder show only "not available" or
>   BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB.   With command line:  slmgr –dli  you
>   can get a "Partial product key" – the last 5 characters of the product
>   key. This "Partial product key" is saved in encrypted form in the
>   certificate file "tokens.dat"
>   (C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\tokens.dat).
>   Everyone who fears that his key can be stolen can also delete manually
>   the product key from registry with this command line:  slmgr –cpky 
>   (cpky = clear product key = remove product key from the registry)

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search shows many people with the same problem.  One solution seems to be to get the DigitalProductID4 value if DigitalProductID is all B's.